# No space above first \item inside mdframed

Tags: spacing, lists, minipage, mdframed

### Problem

This is what happens:

[image: Screenshot]

But I want the same vertical spacing before the first list item *inside* the `mdframed` environment as *outside* of it. How can I do this?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}

\paragraph{inside mdframed:}
\begin{mdframed}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Lorem
        \item Ipsum
        \item Dolor
    \end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}

\paragraph{outside mdframed:}~\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem
    \item Ipsum
    \item Dolor
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### First thoughts

I already read about this issue in combination with the `minipage` environment, but does `mdframed` use `minipages` internally? If it would do so, there would be no pagebreaking possible, would it?

Comment: Which version do you use? Did you try the current version at github?

Comment: I use `mdframed 2012/09/21 1.6d` – will look at github in an instant.

Comment: It's an old version.

Comment: I had the same problem. Updating `mdframed` fixed it.

Comment: The problem disappears in the current version — I'm sorry `-.-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that:

[image]

If I add `\listfiles` I get the following, do you have the latest versions?

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
mdframed.sty    2013/03/09\ 1.8: mdframed
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  xparse.sty    2013/03/12 v4467 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2013/01/08 v4420 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2013/02/03 v4458 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/01/08 v4415 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/01/12 v4434 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2013/02/13 v4459 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/01/08 v4414 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/01/09 v4423 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/01/08 v4412 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/01/14 v4446 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/02/24 v4461 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2013/01/19 v4449 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/01/08 v4411 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2013/03/14 v4468 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
md-frame-0.mdf    2013/03/09\ 1.8: md-frame-0
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```